# Passing URL from MySql via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to work out how to pass a URL that's stored in a MySQL database and attach it to a image. 
The script i have so far is this:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("**********","*********","******","********");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$selectedOption = $_POST["mySelect"];

$result = mysqli_query($con, 
   sprintf("SELECT * FROM `SouthYorkshire` WHERE  `EstProv` = '%s'",
      preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]/", '', $selectedOption)
   )
); // pattern based on your html select options

echo "<div id=\"Results\">";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<div class=\"ClubName\">";
   echo $row['EstName'];
   echo "</div><br>";
   echo "<div class=\"Location\">";
   echo $row['EstAddress2'];
   echo "</div>";
   echo "<br>";
   echo "<div id=\"website\"><img src=\"photos/visit-website-button.png\" width=\"75\" height=\"25\" /></div>";
}
echo date("Y") . " " ."Search is Powered by PHP.";
echo "</div>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

the bit i'm trying to change is :
`echo "<div id=\"website\"><img src=\"photos/visit-website-button.png\" width=\"75\" height=\"25\" /></div>"`

I tried to use the same above with `$row['EstWebsite']`

But am not having any success, any suggestions would be great.

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to make that image a link?

Comment: It was yeah, i think i have it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't matter where the URL comes from, in the end it's just a string of data, and you're just going to be building some HTML with it, so

```
echo '<div id="website"><a href="' . $url . '"><img blah blah blah></a>";
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-add this           ^^^^--add this
```

Comment: It might not be necessary here, but in the general case, the above should read `... <a href="' . htmlspecialchars ($url) . '">...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
echo "<div id=\"website\"><img src=\"" . $row['ImageColumnName'] ."\" width=\"75\" height=\"25\" /></div>";
```

Comment: It wasn't that exactly but you did jog my memory as to what i had forgotten, this is the code i ended up with

    echo "<div id=\"website\"><a href=\"" . $row['EstWebsite'] ."\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"photos/visit-website-button.png\" width=\"75\" height=\"25\" /></div></a>";

Have just tested this and works thank you for your help :)